# recursively rename files within a specific directory to have name of parent

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a post-process directory, which is now called "filemove"

Within this directory, i have thousands of directories, named:
folder 1
folder 2
folder 3
etc.

Within THOSE directories, I am wanting to rename the *single* file within each to own the name of the parent directory. I've tried about 20 solutions thus far, and I'm running into the following problems:

1.) the solutions don't assume I'm running the batch file outside of the directory i want to rename - as such, everything in my main dir gets renamed. it must target directories specifically in "filemove"

2.) some just don't rename some files...I suppose it might be regex issue?

3.) some MOVE the file and rename - I want them to remain where they are, just be renamed to have the same name as the parent directory

4.) I've had most success with a script which appended the directory name to the filename - but I have not been successful in having it ONLY rename the file to the parent name, not appending.

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Which version of windows are you running? Can we use PowerShell commands?

Can you elaborate on the ways you have tried? Maybe we can just fix one of those?

Comment: Thanks @CameronTacklind. I'm not opposed to powershell, I just have limited exposure to it.

I am on windows 10. Would it be best to link the methods I have tried?

Comment: Post your code for number 4 (the one you've had the most success with) so we can take a look at what you're working with.

Comment: The purpose of StackOverFlow is to help you with existing code you are trying to use. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).